# Deep Neural Networks - Improve performance of text classification

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, text-classification

I have an NLP classification problem to classify short phrases/words into one of two categories. The features are in the form of words and short phrases where some of the the words and phrases repeat themselves in a particular observation. For example

```
|                     Observation                    |  label |
|:--------------------------------------------------:|:------:|
| 'dog, jump, eat, drink water, jump'                | animal |
| 'run, jump, travel, sleep, talk, grocery shopping' | human  |
| 'swim, language, jump, eat, go to school'          | human  |
| 'bite, lick, growl, eat, run, lick, scratch'       | animal |
```

I've tried using affine DNN and ConvNets with tokenized(CountVectorizer and TFIDVectorizer) input text, also with tokenized input + word embeddings with and without regularization. Validation accuracy never seems to exceed 76%. Any ways on how to improve performance of my model?

Comment: What kind of `Dense` networks have you used?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I've tried a 1-4 layer `Dense` network with number of neurons ranging from `100-500` in the hidden layers. After vectorization my dataset is shape is `(m, 680)` where `m` is the number of observations.